# Angularjs How can I get the path at transformRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Anyone know how can I get path inside interceptors in AnngularJs

Basically I need to do a condition to avoide animations for couple of Api requests.

here is below my code

```
var CRMSWebPortal = angular.module('CRMSWebPortal', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

CRMSWebPortal.factory('httpPreConfig', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {

    $http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data) {
        //------I need path for all external api calls here???
        $rootScope.$broadcast('httpCallStarted');
        return data;
    });

    $http.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('httpCallStopped');
        return data;
    });

    return $http;
}]);


CRMSWebPortal.run(['$rootScope', 'httpPreConfig', function ($rootScope, httpPreConfig) {

    $rootScope.$on("httpCallStarted", function () {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<p><img class="loading"> Just a moment...</p>',
        });
    });

    $rootScope.$on("httpCallStopped", function () {
        $.unblockUI();
    });
}]);
```

Comment: probably write a service that contains all your apiendpoints, and then inject it at your factory?

Comment: Transformers are not interceptors. Use interceptors to do that. They get the whole config object which includes url, data, headers, etc. For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Comment: @CozyAzure Thank you for that, any documents to help me in that direction?

Comment: @georgeawg I looked at that document earlier. it was not working for me, may be I implemented the wrong way.. will try again with it. Thank you